# IOUtils.copy throws IOException for files larger than ~1 mb

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Apache Commons IO's IOUtils.copy to make copies of existing files, on Google Cloud Storage.

Here is the problem: if the files goes beyond around 1 mb, `IOUtils.copy` will throw an exception. Files below 1 mb works perfectly fine.

**Code snippet**

```
            AppEngineFile newFile = null;
            GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder().setBucket("bucket-name")
            .setKey(newFilename).setMimeType("image/jpeg");

    try {

        //currentFile is an instance of a AppEngineFile
        FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(currentFile, true);

        newFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(newFile, true);

        InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);
        OutputStream outputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);

        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        writeChannel.closeFinally();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warning(e.toString());
    }
```

**I also attempted a more primitive method**: but it doesn't work too

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = inputStream.read(buffer);
while (len != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    len = inputStream.read(buffer);
}
```

My assumption now: there is some kind of restriction on the App Engine platform.

Note: I've also tried `IOUtiles.copyLarge` (which is meant for files larger than 2 GB), but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a smaller than 1mb buffer. Latest appengine version reduced buffer size.